# Django group by field and get all items related to that particular field

Tags: python, django

I'm using Django 3.1.1 and I've got a News model which has a field called source_name.

```py
class News(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=350)
    content = RichTextField(blank=True, null=True)
    link = models.URLField(max_length=500, unique=True)

    # Source
    source_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

I want to group each news by source_name and for each source i want to get all the news.

```
News(title='test',source_name='AAA',...)
News(title='test-1',source_name='AAA',...)
News(title='test-2',source_name='AAA',...)
News(title='test-B',source_name='BBB',...)
News(title='test-B1',source_name='BBB',...)
```

In the html template I want to get the following output

```
- AAA
  -test
  -test-1
  -test-2
- BBB
  -test-B
  -test-B1
```

It would be so easy if I could the following loops:

```
{% for source in source_names %}
    {{ source }}
    {% for news in source %}
        {{news.title}}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

How can I achieve the above descriped output in the django template?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

just prepare the data as you want them organized:

```
source_values = ['a', 'b', 'c']
data = { s: News.objects.filter(source=s) for s in source_values }
```

and then in the template

```
{% for source, news_list in data.items %}
    {{source}}
    {% for n in news_list %}
        {{n.title}}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix the issue following this snippet.

```py
grouped = {} #dict
for obj in News.objects.all():
    grouped.setdefault(obj.type, []).append(obj)
```

and in the template I used:

```
{% for source, news_list in grouped.items %}
    {{source}}
    {% for n in news_list %}
        {{n.title}}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```